# Can someone explain this behavior in javascript?

Tags: javascript, casting

Tested in Firefox:

```
a = [] + 0;
b = 0;

alert(a); // 0
alert(b); // 0

alert(!a); // false
alert(!b); // true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `+` [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) causes a `toString` evaluation of `0`.

As such the value of `a` is `"0"`, while the value of `b` is `0`.

From **ECMAScript 11.6.1 The Addition operator(+)**

> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition. The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>
>    a.   Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the
>      Note below 11.6.3.
>
> NOTE 1 No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5 and 6. All native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence of a hint as if the hint String were given. Host objects may handle the absence of a hint in some other manner.
>
> NOTE 2 Step 7 differs from step 3 of the comparison algorithm for the relational operators (11.8.5), by using the logical-or operation instead of the logical-and operation.

Answer (score 3):

`[] + 0` is a string.
When you write `a + b` in Javascript, the engine will convert both `a` and `b` to primitives.
If at least one of the resulting primitives is a string, it will perform string concatenation; otherwise, it will perform numeric addition.

To convert an object (such as an array) to a primitive, the engine will call `valueOf()`, and, if its result is not a primitive, will call `toString()`.
For arrays, `valueOf()` returns the original array (which is not a primitive) and `toString()` returns comma-separated string of the array's contents.

Therefore, `[] + 0` becomes `"" + 0`, which is `"0"`.

Non-empty strings are never falsy.